# Aquamacs failed to download melpa archive

Tags: emacs, aquamacs, melpa

I am using Aquamacs 3.3 based on Emacs GNU Emacs 25.1.1

My ~/Library/../Preferences.el file includes the instructions for melpa.

```
(require 'package)
;; Marmalade
;;(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
```

I toggle-debug-on-error so I can get the following message why:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Archive location https://stable.melpa.org/packages/ is not an absolute file name")
signal(error ("Archive location https://stable.melpa.org/packages/ is not an absolute file name"))
#[128 "\300\301\302\303\"C\"\207" [signal error apply format-message] 6 2502308]("Archive location %s is not an absolute file name" "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/")
apply(#[128 "\300\301\302\303\"C\"\207" [signal error apply format-message] 6 2502308] ("Archive location %s is not an absolute file name" "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
(with-no-warnings (apply ad--addoit-function args))
(setq ad-return-value (with-no-warnings (apply ad--addoit-function args)))
(if aquamacs-ring-bell-on-error-flag (progn (aquamacs-bell) (setq ad-return-value (with-no-warnings (apply ad--addoit-function args)))) (setq ad-return-value (with-no-warnings (apply ad--addoit-function args))))
(let (ad-return-value) (if aquamacs-ring-bell-on-error-flag (progn (aquamacs-bell) (setq ad-return-value (with-no-warnings (apply ad--addoit-function args)))) (setq ad-return-value (with-no-warnings (apply ad--addoit-function args)))) ad-return-value)
ad-Advice-error(#[128 "\300\301\302\303\"C\"\207" [signal error apply format-message] 6 2502308] "Archive location %s is not an absolute file name" "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/")
apply(ad-Advice-error #[128 "\300\301\302\303\"C\"\207" [signal error apply format-message] 6 2502308] ("Archive location %s is not an absolute file name" "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
error("Archive location %s is not an absolute file name" "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/")
(if (file-name-absolute-p (cdr archive)) nil (error "Archive location %s is not an absolute file name" (cdr archive)))
(if http (progn (package-handle-response) (re-search-forward "^$" nil (quote move)) (forward-char) (delete-region (point-min) (point))) (if (file-name-absolute-p (cdr archive)) nil (error "Archive location %s is not an absolute file name" (cdr archive))) (insert-file-contents (expand-file-name file (cdr archive))))
(save-current-buffer (set-buffer buffer) (if http (progn (package-handle-response) (re-search-forward "^$" nil (quote move)) (forward-char) (delete-region (point-min) (point))) (if (file-name-absolute-p (cdr archive)) nil (error "Archive location %s is not an absolute file name" (cdr archive))) (insert-file-contents (expand-file-name file (cdr archive)))) (if (listp (read buffer)) (progn (make-directory dir t) (setq buffer-file-name (expand-file-name file dir)) (let ((version-control (quote never))) (save-buffer)))))
(prog1 (save-current-buffer (set-buffer buffer) (if http (progn (package-handle-response) (re-search-forward "^$" nil (quote move)) (forward-char) (delete-region (point-min) (point))) (if (file-name-absolute-p (cdr archive)) nil (error "Archive location %s is not an absolute file name" (cdr archive))) (insert-file-contents (expand-file-name file (cdr archive)))) (if (listp (read buffer)) (progn (make-directory dir t) (setq buffer-file-name (expand-file-name file dir)) (let ((version-control (quote never))) (save-buffer))))) (kill-buffer buffer))
(let* ((http (string-match "\\`http:" (cdr archive))) (buffer (if http (url-retrieve-synchronously (concat (cdr archive) file)) (generate-new-buffer "*package work buffer*")))) (prog1 (save-current-buffer (set-buffer buffer) (if http (progn (package-handle-response) (re-search-forward "^$" nil (quote move)) (forward-char) (delete-region (point-min) (point))) (if (file-name-absolute-p (cdr archive)) nil (error "Archive location %s is not an absolute file name" (cdr archive))) (insert-file-contents (expand-file-name file (cdr archive)))) (if (listp (read buffer)) (progn (make-directory dir t) (setq buffer-file-name (expand-file-name file dir)) (let ((version-control ...)) (save-buffer))))) (kill-buffer buffer)))
(let* ((dir (expand-file-name "archives" package-user-dir)) (dir (expand-file-name (car archive) dir))) (let* ((http (string-match "\\`http:" (cdr archive))) (buffer (if http (url-retrieve-synchronously (concat (cdr archive) file)) (generate-new-buffer "*package work buffer*")))) (prog1 (save-current-buffer (set-buffer buffer) (if http (progn (package-handle-response) (re-search-forward "^$" nil (quote move)) (forward-char) (delete-region (point-min) (point))) (if (file-name-absolute-p (cdr archive)) nil (error "Archive location %s is not an absolute file name" (cdr archive))) (insert-file-contents (expand-file-name file (cdr archive)))) (if (listp (read buffer)) (progn (make-directory dir t) (setq buffer-file-name (expand-file-name file dir)) (let (...) (save-buffer))))) (kill-buffer buffer))))
package--download-one-archive(("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") "archive-contents")
(condition-case nil (package--download-one-archive archive "archive-contents") ((debug error) (message "Failed to download `%s' archive." (car archive))))
(while --dolist-tail-- (setq archive (car --dolist-tail--)) (condition-case nil (package--download-one-archive archive "archive-contents") ((debug error) (message "Failed to download `%s' archive." (car archive)))) (setq --dolist-tail-- (cdr --dolist-tail--)))
(let ((--dolist-tail-- package-archives) archive) (while --dolist-tail-- (setq archive (car --dolist-tail--)) (condition-case nil (package--download-one-archive archive "archive-contents") ((debug error) (message "Failed to download `%s' archive." (car archive)))) (setq --dolist-tail-- (cdr --dolist-tail--))))
package-refresh-contents()
package-list-packages()
funcall-interactively(package-list-packages)
call-interactively(package-list-packages record nil)
command-execute(package-list-packages record)
execute-extended-command(nil "package-list-packages" "package-li")
funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "package-list-packages" "package-li")
call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

I would think that the location in the message (SO won't let me type it here) with the trailing slash was absolute enough.

Other people who have run into something similar have
1) melpa site was down or rebuilding.  My text-only version of emacs downloads melpa just fine.  It looks up to me.
2) running Emacs 24.  I'm on 25.

What is causing this?  How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are still trying to access melpa-stable, but your init indicates you are trying to connect to melpa. There is some compiled byte-code in that backtrace. You don't happen to have a byte-code (compiled) version of your init file do you?

That aside, I've seen odd error messages like this when Emacs has not been built with gnuTLS support (and therefore cannot do https).

Comment: Aquamacs is a strange animal.  I'll look around.

Comment: did not find any .emacs.elc .  All .elc files looks like they were clearly part of a package

Comment: Do a C-h v on package-archives and see what it contains. It looks like it is still trying to access melpa-stable, but you have that line commnted out, so something isn't right. You may need to delete .emacs.d/elpa and start again.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Aquamacs and normal emacs are fighting.  I've found some oddness in ~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/customizations.el

I think that's the lead I needed.